# Prevent `xcodebuild clean` from updating SPM dependencies

Tags: xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I am using Fastlane to build an iOS application that uses Swift Package Manager integrated into Xcode. Some of my dependencies are in private Git repositories that require authentication.

I have a simple lane for cleaning all build artifacts like this:

```
desc "Clean"
lane :clean do
  clean_build_artifacts
  clear_derived_data
  xcclean
end
```

The problem I have is that I want to be able to run this lane without being prompted for Git credentials. The `xcclean` action calls the `xcodebuild clean` command which tries to resolve all packages (and therefore prompts for credentials).

The `xcodebuild` command for actually doing a build doesn't resolve packages (you need to call `xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies` for that) but the `clean` command doesn't seem to have any argument that can be used to turn off automatic dependency resolution.

Is there a way to stop `xcodebuild clean` from trying to resolve dependencies? Alternatively, is there some other equivalent command I can use instead of `xcclean`?

Comment: I decided this should be filed as a   ̶B̶u̶g̶ ̶R̶e̶p̶o̶r̶t̶ Feedback to Apple. Here is the OpenRadar tracker for it: https://openradar.appspot.com/FB9737989